# Setting a file name from a form in CodeIngiter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, filenames

I'm a novice in programming and hence this question might look too dumb. My task is to set a variable called "filename" from a form that has three fileds that need to be submitted by the user. For example the file name should be: Filename=(Field1Data)+(Field2Data)+(Field3Data). I was trying to use something like: `'file_name' => set_value('enter_product_name')_set_value('test_type')_set_value('test_unit')`

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'file_name' => $this->input->post('data1').$this->input->post('data2').$this->input->post('data3');

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: I can help if u add  ur controller and view to the question

Comment: I added my controller for your reference. Thanks for your time.

Comment: if ur submitting the form using POST method, then the value must be retrieved using $this->input->post('test_type'); not set_value('test_type');

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I used  $file_name=$this->input->post('test_type').'_'.$this->input->post('test_unit');